# Intuition behind chosing coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-transforms

Once given the right coordinates (polar, sphere, cylindric) I am able to determine the value of a given integral. But how do I know, if the coordinates are not explicitly given, which coordinates to chose?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of switching coordinates is to *exploit symmetries*. The typical example is radial symmetry. Assume you want to integrate a function 
$$
f=f(x_1\ldots x_n)$$
that is *radially symmetric*, that is $f(\boldsymbol x)=g(|\boldsymbol x|)$ for a function $g=g(r)$ of a single variable, over a ball (=a radially symmetric domain). Then choosing polar coordinates the multiple integral reduces to a single-variable integral, with a significant simplification.

This is a paradigm in the choice of coordinate system. It is generally a good idea to choose a system that is *adapted* to the symmetries of the problem.